# multiple Unique Key in oracle is not working?

Tags: oracle

I'm having Multiple unique key where i want no duplication in the database but it is generating the duplication after the implementation 
My unique keys are TELEPHONE, EMAIL and CODE.

The code is generated by SQL Devloper.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERMASTER 
(
  NAME VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, CODE NUMBER NOT NULL 
, ADDRESS VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
, TELEPHONE NUMBER 
, EMAIL VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE SYSTEM 
PCTFREE 10 
PCTUSED 40 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  FREELISTS 1 
  FREELIST GROUPS 1 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL;

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERMASTER
ADD CONSTRAINT CUSTOMERMASTER_UK1 UNIQUE 
(
  TELEPHONE 
, EMAIL 
, CODE 
)
DISABLE;
```

Comment: Why DISABLE at the end of the script?

Comment: After enabling it as I'm inserting data the data is not inserted

Comment: why `java` and `swing` tags?

Comment: actually this database is connected with swings and java too from there no problem is coming if it is i'll check it out once again @Jean-BaptisteYunès

Comment: but your question has nothing to do with both, so don't use them

Comment: *"After enabling it as I'm inserting data the data is not inserted"*: Isn't this what this is all about? The constraint forbids you to have duplicates in the table so trying to insert duplicates fails. Obviously your insert statement tries to insert one or more duplicate records and the constraint proves it's working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want unique email, unique telephone and unique code the code is:

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERMASTER
ADD CONSTRAINT CUSTOMERMASTER_UK_TEL UNIQUE 
(
  TELEPHONE 
)
;

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERMASTER
ADD CONSTRAINT CUSTOMERMASTER_UK_EMAIL UNIQUE 
(
EMAIL 
)
;

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERMASTER
ADD CONSTRAINT CUSTOMERMASTER_UK_CODE UNIQUE 
(
CODE 
)
;
```

If you want unique combination of telefone, email and code together, the constraint is ok, you just need to put it enabled.

Comment: When I'm adding data to it it is making duplication for example If I have added one entry with code 98 and after that I'm adding second entry with same code and telephone now I'm adding email to it then the data displays a duplicate entry too